# Kerberos Errors

Tags: kerberos, errors

Need help with the below error. I haven't been able to find much that has helped.

```
Event Source: Security-Kerberos
Event ID: 4
    Qualifiers: 16384
Version: 0
Level: 2
Task: 0
Opcode: 0
Keywords: 0x80000000000000
```

> The Kerberos client received a KRB_AP_ERR_MODIFIED error from the
>   server D@@@@@$. The target name used was DOMAIN\DS@@@@@$. This
>   indicates that the target server failed to decrypt the ticket provided
>   by the client. This can occur when the target server principal name
>   (SPN) is registered on an account other than the account the target
>   service is using. Please ensure that the target SPN is registered on,
>   and only registered on, the account used by the server. This error can
>   also happen when the target service is using a different password for
>   the target service account than what the Kerberos Key Distribution
>   Center (KDC) has for the target service account. Please ensure that
>   the service on the server and the KDC are both updated to use the
>   current password. If the server name is not fully qualified, and the
>   target domain (My.FQDN.ORG) is different from the client domain
>   (My.FQDN.ORG), check if there are identically named server accounts in
>   these two domains, or use the fully-qualified name to identify the
>   server.

A little background. We have been experiencing random issues with our DCs. Typically after a few months one of them will no longer allow us to login. If we turn off Kerberos on that DC we can log back in, but that is causing all sorts of other issues. Typically we just blow it out and create another DC which last for a couple of months, however, I need to get to the bottom of the problem. Along with the kerberos error we are seeing group policy errors and AD replication errors, but my guess is that they are caused by an authentication problem. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/558115

Further, possibly the client ticket cache is corrupt and sending a poorly formed response.

Identify the client and server and try taking some tcpdumps. Walk through the full set of steps in Kerberos and see what step is broken.